# How can I reinstall packages accidentally removed when trying to remove another package?

Tags: gnome, apt, rhythmbox, gimp, gstreamer

I accidently executed `sudo apt-get remove --purge gstreamer0.10`, and the packages such as **gimp**, **gnome-**, **Rhythmbox** and etc are removed, so I forced to stop the processing, but I don't remember what packages were deleted. How can I *reinstall* the packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I forced to stop the processing

If you mean that you halted the package manager during its work, this is a bad idea.  Much better to just let it do what it's doing, then reverse it later.

If apt-get now refuses to work because a previous operation was interrupted, you can try `dpkg --configure -a` and `apt-get install -f` to try and fix the problem.  But it's not *guaranteed* to work.

> I don't remember what packages were deleted

You can have a look at the DPKG log as described in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/175504/how-do-i-get-the-history-of-apt-get-install-on-unbuntu).  It points out that the DPKG log is at: `/var/log/dpkg.log` and it should show the packages that were installed or removed.

In general however, I believe that installing the metapackage `ubuntu-desktop` should restore any missing packages that normally come with an Ubuntu desktop install.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If you need to individually install all the separate packages, it may mark some dependencies as "manually installed" which can leave around extra cruft during future upgrades.

Comment: Yeah, I already knew that is a bad thing, but at the moment I was kind of scary so I stopped the processing. Thanks!